# Navigation list is not centering properly

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm learning how to code Wordpress themes currently, and I'm having trouble centering my navigation menu. It moves too far to the right. I have included an image to illustrate the problem with the code that I have presented.

Here is a link to a screenshot of the problem: http://i59.tinypic.com/8z1m2o.png

```
body {
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #333;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* General Layout */
div.container{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

article.post {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}

article.post:last-of-type{
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Header */
.site-header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Footer */
.site-footer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Navigation */
.site-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left:50%;
}

.site-nav ul{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.site-nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.site-nav ul li:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.site-nav` has `position: fixed, left: 50%` so the left side of the element will be positioned in the middle of the screen. Remove this rule or give the element `margin-left: -X` where X is equal to half of `.site-nav`'s width if you must use fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
.site-nav {

    width: 100%
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-nav ul{

    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/33jlmoo.png) It seems to think that this position is the center. I've been having this issue with the navigation the whole time. Any other ideas?